# Find a point on function graph that has a fixed arc-length distance from another point

Tags: functions, definite-integrals, computational-mathematics, arc-length, inverse-problems

The problem (as often is in math) is finding $x$: 
\begin{equation}
d = \int_{x_0}^x\sqrt{1+[f'(t)]^2} \ \text{dt}
\end{equation}
It's an inverse problem, and I'm looking for an approximation of the solution for computational purposes. I'm trying to distribute evenly arc-lenght spaced points along the graph of a given real function.

Using the Riemann sum for the integral gives me no hope...any help?
EDIT: the Riemann-sum approach (with a subdivision of the interval $[x_0,x]$ in $N$ sub-intervals) looks like this, with $dt\simeq \Delta t:=\frac{1}{N}(x-x_0)$:
\begin{equation}
d = \Delta t\sum_{k=0}^N\sqrt{1+[f'(x_k)]^2}=\frac{x-x_0}{N}\sum_{k=0}^N\sqrt{1+\Delta t^2\left[f(x_0+(k+1)\Delta t)-f(x_0+k\Delta t)\right]^2}
\end{equation}
where we're using
\begin{equation}
f'(x_k)\simeq N\frac{f(x_{k+1})-f(x_k)}{x-x_0}
\end{equation}

Comment: Maybe not...I'm looking for a computable solution, not really an analytical one

Comment: My bad, but I thought it would work to compute $f'$ analytically and then integrate numerically? I think you could make all symbolic calculations a priori by hand and then give the numbers to the computer? Please tell me if there are problems in my idea